# How to pass pd column or series as a variable into plt.plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Base don my calculations, my application produces a variable number of data frame columns with different names.

I am trying to plot these but am struggling to work out how to pass the column names as a variable into pyplot but am missing the obvious.

It works fine if I specify an individual column name but how do I pass that in as a variable?

```
ax.plot( df.dti, df['ma_11'] )   # Works but next time it could be ma_12

str='ma_12'
ax.plot( df.dti, df[str?????] )  # How to pass str into the plot function?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you have a range, you can use this:

```
for in range(min_ma, max_ma + 1):
    ax.plot(df.dti, df['ma_{}'.format(i)])
```